# Nginx glob in try_files

Tags: nginx, configuration

Is it possible in nginx to do something that is the equivalent of a file path glob in `try_files`?

```
server {
  try_files /var/www/*/assets/$uri;
}
```

That is, if `/var/www/` contained `site_a` and `site_b`, which both contained an `assets` directory, this would perform the equivalent of

```
server {
  try_files /var/www/site_a/assets/$uri /var/www/site_b/assets/$uri;
}
```

I'm trying to see if this is possible without having to reference the directories currently residing in `/var/www`.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Not with default modules. If you have a few paths, just list them all. If there is a lot of paths, write script to generate node config.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyTen. I was leaning in that direction, but wanted to be sure.